# How to bake a Stack Overflow Cake?

Tags: cake

As I approach 10k points on Stack Overflow, I would like to make a cake to celebrate. All the layers in the stack of the Stack Overflow logo are orange, but what would they taste like?

Carrot? Orange? Banana-Strawberry? Mango-Cherry?

Did anyone else make a Stack Overflow cake who can give some tips?

Comment: Hi, congratulations on your rep! I am afraid that even the sites with a "softer" topic than SO on the network still follow the idea of objective questions only, and not being a discussion forum. So, your question is fun, but sadly falls squarely into the kind of thing we cannot answer. I hope your cake turns out well though.

Comment: But you are of course invited to discuss this topic in the Frying Pan ([chat])!

Comment: Refactor into a question about recommendations for the best colourings and aromatics to use for each layer in this application. Discussion about WHICH colours and flavour results to strive for belongs on meta :)